# Laravel - Interactive User Setup

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Essentially what I am trying to do is to create an interactive user set up wizard (often seen in CMSes like Wordpress or xenforo) when they first run the project. This would consist of basic configuration such as setting the parameters to the MySQL database, setting up and admin account, etc. The issue is, I'm not too sure how to go about going this in the first place. How would I go about overwriting values in the configuration file properly? What would be the best implementation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?
[Laravel Setup Wizard](https://github.com/marvinlabs/laravel-setup-wizard/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: This should be a comment, as link-only answers can go stale and become useless for future users. Alternatively, include the relevant section here.